# Extract numbers from text and text cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need a SUM from an column of cells that contains text and numbers.The data style looks like this.

```
TwoD crowd still: 15
ThreeD crowd traveling: 22
ThreeD crowd establisher: 22
Reactive behavioral crowd: 24
```

I have found a link to a solution, which is a `.xlam` file. But I don't know how to run it.
http://www.financeforexcel.com/post/Excel-Add-in-Extract-Numbers-from-Text.aspx

What would be the best way to SUM the list?
Thanks

Comment: To keep your worksheet clean, maybe a text to column on the : might be a solution to consider. This will extract the number and place it in a separate column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using the add-in

To use the addin you've downloaded, just double-click on the file and activate the macro. You will then have a new button in the ribbon (this will only work if you have Excel 2007 or higher) that will work as described in the link you gave in your question.

#### Using formulas

You can deal with your case with formulas:

On a new column, add this formula:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,999))
```

or (credits to [J.P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190829/jp) from the comments) this better one:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1)-1)
```

and drag the formula till the end of your values

Add a formula to SUM the total:

```
=SUM(B1:B10)
```

[EDIT] or see the comment from [barry houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini) below. Using a `SUMPRODUCT`  and a `REPLACE`, you can do it in one shot! :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REPLACE(A1:A4,1,FIND(":",A1:A4),"")+0)
```

Comment: Why would the SUM formula be a array formula?

Comment: Because I *ahem * forgot to add the `VALUE` needed to convert the formula result to number. Writing this make me think I could have done that on the formula before - I will edit my post, sorry if our comments will no longer mean anything - have a look at the revision history if needed

Comment: @Arnoldiusss: thanks for pointing out the inconsistency of my answer. I've improved it

Comment: Check! btw i always use -- to convert to a number like: --MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,999)  . Didnt know of the VALUE funtion

Comment: @Arnoldiusss: That's also a good way, I am simply more familiar to `VALUE` :)

Comment: @JP.: nice one, your solution is cleaner than mine because it avoids the artificial `999` number of cars

Comment: LOL that's exactly what I was thinking -- avoid the arbitrary number of characters that `MID` always seems to require.

Comment: Save another function call by using REPLACE, i.e. `=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(":",A1),"")+0`.....then sum the results.....or extract values and sum all in one with `=SUMPRODUCT(REPLACE(A1:A4,1,FIND(":",A1:A4),"")+0)`, assumes that all cells have data in the same format....

Comment: @barryhoudini: this is surely the best solution. I've edited my answer, thanks.